# UIView not appearing over keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-softkeyboard

I have this code:

```
JMenuController *menuController = [[JMenuController alloc] init];
    NSArray *buttonsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"From Libary", @"Take Photo or Video", nil];
    [menuController showMenuWithTitle:@"Add Media" ButtonTitles:buttonsArray animated:YES];
    self.currentMenuType = JCreateMenuTypeNewMedia;

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:menuController];
```

The problem is, the view appears below the keyboard, which is already on screen. How do i fix this?

Comment: Got scared for a while, I thought Oracle introduced "UISwing"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it took awhile for me to understand what you wanted to do. You have 2 options.

- Resign the keyboard and show the view with the buttons.
- Use a UIActionSheet to display the buttons over the keyboard like it does in the Messages application when you press the camera to send a picture to someone.

I would recommend the later.

Edit:
Take a look at this for your custom UIActionSheet [Show a view over the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544042/show-a-view-over-the-keyboard)

Comment: I essentially have made my own action sheet, rather than use the default one. So i want to copy the behaviour of UIActionSheet.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to display some view on top of the keyboard is put that view inside a `UIWindow` for which you set the `windowLevel` property to `UIWindowLevelAlert`. Something like:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

UIWindow *myWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
myWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
[myWindow addSubview:myView];

[myWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

If you're using ARC, make sure you keep a strong reference to myWindow. Otherwise, it'll get automatically released and so it won't get added to your application windows.

*(This is how UIActionSheet and UIAlertView work internally. When one of them is visible, have a look at [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows and you'll see they create windows with their windowLevel set to UIWindowLevelAlert.)*

Comment: Thanks! then I also need to hide it by `[myWindow setHidden:YES];`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me but once I dismiss the view I am not able to interact with my UI. Also there is a starange behaviour in Keyboard. My focus is still in UItextField & if I press any key there is no change in my textfield, but if I press backspace my text gets deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard exists in its own window. To put things over it, you either have to put things into the keyboard's window (this is not a supported behavior), or create yet another window and put it over the keyboard.