# How do I place a subview in front of the keyboard?

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

I hope to insert subview in front of displayed keyboard. I am using the following code:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: myView];
```

but the subview does not display.

Comment: What you really want to do? Because showing a view in front of a "key board" doesn't make a sense. I am sure that you missed something in asking your question. Expand your question with more details that exactly you wants to do. Put any screen shots too if you've.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for, but my best guess is you want to subview a "done"/"return" over the keypad.
You maybe able to do this by doing something like this (when the keyboard comes up)

```
UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];  
UIView* keyboard;  
for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)   
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];  
    // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it  
    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"UIKeyboard"] == YES)  
        [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];  
}
```

The `bringSubviewToFront` idea failed because it (the keyboard) is not a subview of your application.

Comment: From what I can see on iOS 7, the windows property doesn't always have 2 windows. On iOS 8 though, this seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Artyom from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544042/show-a-view-over-the-keyboard)

Rather than using this for loop to find the correct window you can instead use:

```
UIWindow * window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject;

[window addSubview:_menuView];
[window bringSubviewToFront:_menuView];
```

As long as you are adding it while the is keyboard active then the keyboard will always be the last view added and it reduces the code complexity greatly.

Answer (score 0):

@Altaf, the prefix you mention in your code is not the good one. You should use:

```
if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"] == YES)
```

[See an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429211/using-touchpose-to-render-touches-on-ios-screen-with-keyboard-in-demo-applicati), with Touchpose classes to show touches on demo applications, that I modified to display the animation over the keyboard.